# Error Using withTracker (React.createElement: type is invalid)

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I have a component (Board) that calls another component: (BoardCardContainer).

This is the error message:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Board`.

**Board.js:**

```
... bunch of imports
import { BoardCardContainer } from './BoardCardContainer';

export class Board extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderCards() {
    return this.props.cards.map(card => (
      <div key={card._id} style={{ margin: 5 }}>
        <BoardCardContainer /> //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!!
      </div>
    ));
  }    
  render() { ... }
}
```

**./BoardCardContainer.js**

```
... bunch of imports
export default BoardCardContainer = withTracker(() => { ... })(BoardCard);
```

Comment: Are you sure all this code is relevant for your question? If not giving only what is absolutely needed for reproducing the error would give you better & faster answers.

Comment: It's likely an export/import mismatch; check that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common ES6 error.

Your import:

```
import { BoardCardContainer } from './BoardCardContainer';
```

is importing by *name* but your corresponding export:

```
export default BoardCardContainer = withTracker(() => { ... }
```

is exporting *default*.

Just change your import to:

```
import BoardCardContainer from './BoardCardContainer';
```

Comment: IMO the reactjs team should improve that error message. Everyone runs into this at some point and it's quite obscure at first.